# Running ubuntu from ext4 formatted USB drive?

Tags: usb, ext4

The "Make Startup Disk" ubuntu utility sees it as writable only if it's fat formatted.
If I format it to Ext4, it sees it as 0 free space and doesn't allow to click "Make startup disk" button.

However, since I plan to use the drive to run the OS (not just install) and will store files bigger than 4gb i would like to have bootable usb drive on ext4
Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do what you intend.

**The correct approach** to your desired result is to simply **"Install Ubuntu"** to the external drive rather than use "Make Startup Disk" utility. That utility is designed to create a small boot disk as  a method for troubleshooting and repair or installation, not for running the OS as you intend.

If you want the "Try Ubuntu" Option on the drive as well, you can simply dd the ISO image to the drive as outlined here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Install_and_run_Startup_Disk_Creator_alias_usb-creator

Comment: How does one simply "Install Ubuntu" though?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: @user240891 My testing indicates that you are correct re: Startup Disk Creator requiring FAT

Comment: Install it the very same way one would install on a HDD?

Comment: Yes. I've done this successfully many times. You'll want to install grub on the mbr of the external drive so that it will boot regardless of the system you connect it to. And make sure you have the appropriate device (/dev/sdXY) where XY is the device and partiton to install to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're dealing with a permission problem.

Use:

**`sudo chmod -R a+rwX,o-w /media/[your_drive_name]`**

**`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/[your_drive_name]`**

Then eject the drive and insert again. Now try to create a Startup disk.

Or just boot up a live disc and install Ubuntu to the USB drive instead of the internal HDD.

Comment: Did you test this approach?

Comment: @ElderGeek yeah. I've seen my brother do this. I don't exactly say it'll work for Startup disk utility. But allowing the program to write is one step i think.

Comment: I thought so as well initially, but I can actually rw to the drive under my normal user. 
Also when I use the "Erase disk" button of the "Make Startup Disk" app it formats in fat, so I thought it needs it that way for some reason.